# Youtube API v3 Video Author

Tags: youtube-api

Which Api should I use to get the author of video?
I used https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list but it doesn't give me the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, it was possible with YouTube API v2 by [retrieving information about a single video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol?csw=1#Retrieve_video_entry) and as also mentioned in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303767/how-to-retreive-youtube-video-information-title-author-etc-by-its-id-using-y).

However, since the [YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of March 4, 2014](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol?csw=1#top_of_page) and apparently not all features of v2 have been migrated yet, you may want to open a feature request in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Enhancement%20Request%29).

Lastly, this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193417/is-it-possible-to-get-the-youtube-author-name-for-a-video-using-the-v3-api) might also help.